# Is it possible to retreive energy from the air displaced by a moving car?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, air

Correct me if I'm wrong :
When a car is moving it creates an over pressure on the front and a lower pressure on the back. So, from the point of view of the car, the air hitting the windshield has to move faster to the back of the car than the air not being hit. (I guess the air next to the car still is "hit" but the more far it is from the car the less it gets moved). Am I right for now?

If I am, is it possible to get the energy needed to compress and move the air back in the car by using some kind of wind turbine?

Comment: You don't need a turbine.  You just need to improve the shape of your car so that it slips through the air more easily.

Comment: Anyway the answer is yes. Proof: when your car is sitting on the side of the road and a car or truck passes by you can feel your car pushed slightly back and forth once. Maybe more rebounds but if so weaker. If something is moved you can figure out a way to collect that energy. QED